# Find all solutions/zeros

Tags: trigonometry

Find all solutions in the interval$ [0,2\pi]$:

1)$3\sec^3x=4\sec x$

2)$2\sin^2x+3\sin x+1=0$

3)$\cos x+\sin x \tan x=0$

4)$2\sec^3x+\sec^2x–8\sec x–4=0$

Thnx so much

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: U fixed it up well bud

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the equations?

Comment: Yah i got two of them but i need to chk them but also im stuck on the others

Comment: It is generally expected to put this information (your work so far) in your question. [No, not a description of your work, the actual work.]

Answer (score 0):

Hint!

(i) $3sec^3x=4secx \implies secx(3sec^2x-4)=0$

(ii) $2sin^2x+3sinx+1=0$ is quadratic in $sinx$

(iii) $cosx+sinxtanx=0 \implies \frac {cos^2x+sin^2x} {cosx}=0$ can you have a zero?

(iv) I hope you have some idea now :)

Comment: Im stuck on number 9 is it supposed to be undefined?

Comment: Or in this case #3

Comment: user: re: #3 recall the identity: $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = \;?\;$

Comment: Yah it equals 1